# What is difference between properties assigned to function inside of function and outside the function?

Tags: javascript

```
function foo(){
this.a =2;
};

//assign a property
foo.color = 'red';

//assign a method
foo.sayHello = function(){`enter code here`
alert("hello!");
};
var foo1 = new foo();
console.log(foo.color); //red
console.log(foo1.color); //undefined
```

I have position like this. I can do foo1.a and returns 2.
but if I am doing foo1.color it is undefined. 
Can anyone tell me how to access properties and methods defined outside of the function through instance and what is difference between defining properties inside and outside of the function?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: you can use this.constructor.color or foo1.constructor.color as needed.

Answer (score 1):

`foo.prototype.color = 'red'` will apply that property assignment to all instances of `new foo()`.

This property will apply to all instances, even ones that already exist.

`this.a = 2`, on the other hand, will only apply to the current instance.

Answer (score 1):

The first one defines a property `a` on `this`, which will be an *instance* of the `foo` method when it's called as a constructor (with the `new` operator). Every instance of `foo` will have a copy of this property.

The second one defines a static property `color` on the `foo` function object itself. Instances do not inherit this property.

The third one again defines a static property, `sayHello`, whose value happens to be a function.

If you want to define properties that will be inherited by all instances you need to define them on the `prototype` of the constructor:

```
foo.prototype.color = 'red';
```

In this case, every instance of `foo` has access to the *same* `color` property (rather than their own copy of it as in the very first example).

Answer (score 0):

`foo.prototype.color = 'red'` will apply property assignment to all instances of new foo().

`this.a = 2 // will add property 'a' to the current instance.`

E.g

```
var foo1 = new foo();
console.log(foo.color); // red
```

Executing this function will add  properties to the window object ( here a). It adds it to the window because window is the object that called the function when you execute it like that, and this in a function is the object that called the function.

```
foo() // call foo() using window object.
console.log(this.a); // outputs to 2. Here is should be noted that this refers to window object
```

### [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2JTVP/)